# How to decide the value of $\arctan x$ in a definite integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

[image]

---

This is my question. When it gets the upper bound of $\tan^{-1}(1)$ and lower bound of $\tan^{-1}(-1)$, how does he know $\tan^{-1}(-1)$ is equal to $-\frac{\pi}{4}$ rather than $\frac{3\pi}{4}$, and $\tan^{-1}(1)$ is equal to $\frac{\pi}{4}$ rather than $\frac{5\pi}{4}$?

I've tried to let $\tan^{-1}(1)$ equal to $\frac{\pi}{4}$, and $\tan^{-1}(-1)$ equal to $-\frac{\pi}{4}$, it seems work well except the result is different from the solution.

Comment: Those are the principal values.

Answer (score 3):

$\tan^{-1}$ is a function and so it must be defined in a unique way. By convention, $\tan^{-1}(x)$ is the only real number $\theta$ such that $x=\tan \theta$ but also
$$-\frac{\pi}{2}< \theta < \frac{\pi}{2}$$

Comment: Thank you! I may have missed something important

Answer (score 0):

> how does he know $\tan^{−1}(−1)$ is equal to $−\fracπ4$ rather than $\frac{3π}4$

The definition of $\arctan$ is basically a matter of convention and convenience.  The usual definition of $\arctan$ is such that:

- It is an odd function.
- It is continuous.
- The value it produces are the smallest possible (by absolute value), namely in the range $(-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2)$.

Using the usual definition of $\arctan$, you could define the inverse of $\tan$ to be

$$t(x) = \begin{cases}
\arctan x, &\text{ if } x \geqslant 0 \\
\pi+\arctan x, &\text{ if } x < 0 \\
\end{cases}$$

so that $t(-1)=3\pi/4$.
Then $t(x)$ does not have any of the nice properties of $\arctan$ from above. So while you could use $t$, it's the case that $\arctan$ is usually much more convenient, for example it has a simple power series for $|x|\leqslant1$:

$$\arctan x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$$

or you can represet is as integral like

$$\arctan x=\int\limits_0^x \frac1{1+t^2} dt$$

Comment: To make sure I understand what you mean: 1) The inverse function of tan could be $\pi+arctanx$, $2\pi+arctanx$..., but to save its helpful properties, the convention is to only keep the graph from $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$. 2) You mentioned $t(x)$, do you mean that $t(x)$ should be $\pi + arctanx$ for $x < 0$ if I want to let the inverse of tan equal to $\frac{3\pi}{4}$?

Comment: The problem is that $\tan$ does not have an inverse, which is because $\tan$ is not injective. Hence you have to restrict the domain in such a way that the resulting, restricted function can be inverted. One way is to restrict $\tan$ to (−π/2, π/2). A different choice would be (0, π) without π/2. Restricting the domain of $\tan$ translates to chosing the codomain of $\tan^{-1}$.

Comment: I basically understand. So it sounds like $\begin{equation}t(x)={\begin{cases}  arctanx\\ \pi + arctanx\end{cases}} \end{equation}$ is an inverse function of $tanx$ whose domain is restricted to $(0, \pi)$?

Comment: Yes.  When you restrict tan to that interval, then it is injective and it has an inverse.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification!